# Query to add rows until multiple of 10

Tags: sql

I need a query with a column with row number (probably using ROW_NUMBER() ) and if the result are 8 rows (e.g.) the query should result 10 rows with rows 9 and 10 blank except row number. If the result is 15 rows the result should be 20 rows, and so on...
It is possivel?

Comment: Your efforts so far?

Comment: what languages are you using specifically?

Comment: Which dbms? (ROW_NUMBER() isn't ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, something like this would be done in the application layer.  However, you can do this in SQL:

```
select t.*
from table t
union all
select nulls.*
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all . . . select 10
     ) n cross join
     (select count(*) cnt from table) cnt left join
     table nulls
     on 1 = 0
where 10 * floor(cnt / 10) + n.n <= cnt;
```

The first subquery gets all your data.  The second gets the additional rows with `NULL` values.  It uses a `left join` with "false" condition to get all the columns.